# Vertical align and auto padding for the same height items by CSS

Tags: css

```
<div style="height: 480px;">
    <!-- active and same padding -->
    <div>item 1</div>
    <!-- active and same padding -->
    <div>item 2</div>
    <!-- active and same padding -->
    ...
    <!-- active and same padding -->
    <div>item n</div>
    <!-- active and same padding -->
</div>
```

I have the static height, and all items have both height. But the number of items is not static. I have a function with JS.

```
var padding = ( parentHeight - itemHeight * length ) / ( length + 1 );
var css = {
    paddingBottom: padding,
    paddingTop: $index ? 0 : padding
};
```

May i have a CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

set the height for each of the items -

```
<div class="outer">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.outer div {  
    height: 480px;
}
```

If you want minimum height size use also  -

```
.outer {
    min-height:480px;
}
```

**Update :**

```
.outer {
    padding :  40px 0 ; 
}
```

**Update 2 :**

Use  -

```
.outer div {  
    padding :  40px 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: No, only the outer's height and items' height is static. I need the auto and eqaul padding below and above.

Comment: That's the active outer height, i wanna only the paddings active.

Comment: so you want padding between each item ?